# Is the algorithm that involves enumerating n choose k exponetial

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

Say if we have an algorithm needs to list out all possibilities of choosing k elements from n elements (k<=n), is the time complexity of the particular algorithm exponential and why?

Answer (score 0):

No.

There are n choose k = n!/(k!(n-k)!) possibilities [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)].

Consider that, n choose k = n^k / (k!). [[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula)].

Assuming you are keeping k constant, as n grows, the amount of possibilities increases in polynomial time.

For this example, ignore the (1/(k!)) term because it is constant. If k = 2, and you increase n from 2 to 3, then you have a 2^2 to 3^2 change. An exponential change would be from 2^2 to 2^3. This is not the same.

Keeping k constant and changing n results in a big O of O(n^k) (the 1/(k!) term is constant and you ignore it).

Answer (score 0):

Thinking carefully about the size of the input instance is required since the input instance contains numbers - a basic familiarity with [weak NP-hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_NP-completeness) can also be helpful.

Assume that we fix `k=1` and encode `n` in binary. Since the algorithm must visit `n choose 1 = n` numbers, it takes at least `n` steps. Since the magnitude of the number `n` may be exponential in the size of the input (the number of bits used to encode `n`), the algorithm in the worst case consumes exponential time.

You can get a feel for this exponential-time behavior by writing a simple C program that prints all the numbers from `1` to `n` with `n = 2^64` and see how far you get in a minute. While the input is only `64` bits long, it would take you about `600 years` to print all the numbers assuming that your device can print a million numbers per second.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm that finds all possibilities of choosing k elements from n unique elements (k<=n), does NOT have an exponential time complexity, O(K^n), because it instead has a factorial time complexity, O(n!). The relevant formula is:

```
p = n!/(k!(n-k)!)
```